# ASP.NET Core receive custom config via HTTP to configure Kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

This feels like a simple problem to solve, but in all my searching I'm still yet to find a solution that works for me. Could be another case of not finding what I'm after as I'm not searching the right 'thing', but here we are..

I have a C# Web API program where I want to configure the kestrel server from a config object.

I receive this config into my service via rest call, into a `CustomConfig` object. I can get this config object either in `Program.cs` or in `Startup.cs`, but since I don't want to repeat myself and make additional calls, I don't want to do this in both places.

My preference is to get the config in `Startup.cs` since that's where the rest of my configuration code sits, and is where I'm already using my `CustomConfig` object. However, I can't find a way to configure the kestrel server to use the certificate I'm giving it (in Startup.cs), nor can I see a way to inject this config into `Startup.cs` from `Program.cs`.

In other projects I have passed the location of the PFX file as an environment variable: `ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path` (in which case everything works without additional code config), but in this project all config must be retrieved via rest call, so this is not an option here.

I currently have everything running, but only by making the rest call to get config twice. The current implementation to configure kestrel is storing the PFX in `CustomConfig` as a base64 string, and configuring in `Program.cs`:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    CustomConfig config = CustomConfig() // <- I receive config here
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                    {
                       options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(d =>
                       {
                           byte[] pfxBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(config.Base64PFXBytes);
                           d.ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxBytes, "sslKey");
                       });
                    });
                });
        }
```

### To summarise..

- I have a `CustomConfig` object which is used to configure services in `Startup.cs`
- I want to configure my Kestrel server from my `CustomConfig`

So I'm looking for help to either:

- Get Kestrel to use my PFX within `Startup.cs`
- Pass the `CustomConfig` object from `Program.cs` into `Startup.cs`

Hopefully that makes sense.. Welcome any & all solutions / additional questions for clarity!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered implementing a `IConfigurationProvider`, which will not only have the desired effect, but also integrate with ASP.NET Core seamlessly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider

Comment: Thanks. I'd considered an `IConfigurationProvider` before, but I'm resisting for two reasons: The first is keeping the config as strongly-typed instead of retrieving from an `IConfigurationProvider`, the second is some additional methods on the `CustomConfig` object - not the biggest deal in the world, but some extra conversion between that custom object to configprovider (as it's not simply key/value).

Comment: Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but you can bind config to a strongly typed object: `config.GetSection("KestrelOptions").Get<CustomKestrelOptions>()`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#bind-hierarchical-configuration

Comment: As for additional methods, adding some methods to the typed config might suffice, if not, you can add extension methods to `IConfiguration` which could extract a config section to a type and delegate the work to it (for example, fetching a certificate blob from a remote location). Or you could serialize the blob as base64, to make things easier

Comment: Ah nice! Will take a look at this, could be the right solution.. 

Let me know if I'm understanding this right: Make the rest call in Program.cs, configure Kestrel as above, take the `CustomConfig` object and pass into an `IConfigurationProvider`, into Startup, then while in Startup, pull that section out from config and back into a strongly typed object.

Comment: You don't even need to pass anything. `UseKestrel` has an overload that takes in `WebHostBuilderContext`. Then you can use it to retrieve the config. `webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseKestrel((context, options) => { context.Configuration.GetSection("KestrelConfig").Bind(options); })`

Comment: I can submit a prototype as answer, if you'd like

Comment: I'm still reading through / digesting the link you send through before, but if you wanted to submit a prototype answer I'll not say no! Happy to mark as solved by your solution.

Comment: Sure, I've been thinking of implementing a similar scenario, I figured I should just do it now. I'll share the results with you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET Core abstracts configuration using `IConfiguration` interface. Without going into details, it collects
configurations from various `IConfigurationSource` and layers them on top of each other, which lets us override a
setting that's defined in one source in another source by defining it with the same key.

### 1. Implementing an `IConfigurationSource`

Let's implement an `IConfigurationSource`. We can use `ConfigurationSource` abstract class as our starting point. We'll
use an in-memory implementation, then switch to a remote source.

```cs
class RemoteConfigurationSource : IConfigurationSource
{
    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        return new RemoteConfigurationProvider(_options);
    }

    private class RemoteConfigurationProvider : ConfigurationProvider
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            // TODO: fetch data from the API
            var remoteConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "CertificateOptions:PfxBase64", "MIIKkQIBAz....gfQ" },
                { "CertificateOptions:Password", "secret" },
            };
            Data = remoteConfig;
        }
    }
}
```

Then add this to the configuration builder in the `ConfigureHostConfiguration` callback:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration(builder =>
            {
                // add new source
                builder.AddRemoteConfiguration();
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseKestrel((context, options) =>
                {
                    var certificateOptions = context.Configuration
                        .GetSection(KestrelCertificateOptions.ConfigurationKey)
                        .Get<KestrelCertificateOptions>();
                    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(adapterOptions =>
                        adapterOptions.ServerCertificate = certificateOptions.Certificate);
                });
            });
}

public static class ConfigurationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddRemoteConfiguration(this IConfigurationBuilder builder) =>
        builder.Add(new RemoteConfigurationSource());
}

class KestrelCertificateOptions
{
    public const string ConfigurationKey = "CertificateOptions";
    public string PfxBase64 { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public X509Certificate2 Certificate => new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(PfxBase64), Password);
}
```

When we run the app, ASP.NET Core will load and use our in-memory configuration.

### 2. Fetching configuration data from an API

Now let's fetch the config from a remote API. It needs to return configuration values with sections names delimited with
with a colon `:`. Here's the same config as JSON, filed under `CertificateOptions` section:

```json
{
  "CertificateOptions:PfxBase64": "MII....oCAgfQ",
  "CertificateOptions:Password": "secret"
}
```

Assume the API wraps returns this data wrapped as:

```json
{
  "Application": "MyApp",
  "LastChanged": "2021-08-09 14:38:00",
  "Data": {
    "CertificateOptions:PfxBase64": "MIIK...oCAgfQ",
    "CertificateOptions:Password": "secret"
  }
}
```

so we need to take only `Data` key into account when fetching the data.

```cs
class RemoteConfigurationSource : IConfigurationSource
{
    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        return new RemoteConfigurationProvider();
    }

    private class RemoteConfigurationProvider : ConfigurationProvider
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            // We cannot await this method, so have to do sync-over-async. 
            // Not an issue, because it's a one-time thing.
            var result = LoadRemoteConfig().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Data = result.Data;
        }

        private async Task<RemoteConfigResult> LoadRemoteConfig()
        {
            // We cannot use IHttpClientFactory here, since ServiceProvider isn't even built yet.
            using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            // ... add headers, token to request
            return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<RemoteConfigResult>("https://example.com/path/to/json");
        }
    }

    private class RemoteConfigResult
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

To clean things up a bit, we can move the URL and other credentials to appsettings.json:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    /*...*/
  },
  "RemoteConfiguration": {
    "Url": "https://jsonkeeper.com/b/B78I",
    "ApplicationId": "myconfigappid",
    "Secret": "myconfigapisecret"
  }
}
```

Then build a temporary `IConfiguration` add as many sources as necessary, then fetch these values:

```cs
// Read credentials from appsettings.json
var remoteConfigurationOptions = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
    .Build()
    .GetSection(RemoteConfigurationOptions.ConfigurationKey)
    .Get<RemoteConfigurationOptions>();
    
public class RemoteConfigurationOptions
{
    public const string ConfigurationKey = "RemoteConfiguration";
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Secret { get; set; }
}
```

Then pass this object to our configuration source, which in turns passes it down to the configuration provider

Comment: Wow excactly what i was looking for